# Why does read_csv from readr modifies column names when importing multiple csv files with same column name?

Tags: r

I have many csv files with columns `name`, `age` and `gender`. When I import the csv files to R using `read_csv()` function from `readr` package, it modifies column name of 2nd csv and onward as `name.1`, `age.2`, `gender.3` etc.

Why is this happening? Because of this name modification, it become cumbersome to merge (or wrangle) dataframes as column names does not match anymore.

--- EDIT ---

I have data collected every month on `name`, `age` and `gender`. The data are saved as `Jan_data.csv`, `Feb_data.csv`, `March_data.csv`etc. Let's say at the end of the year, I want to combine all data into single file to do some analysis.

However, when I import to R using read_csv file, `Jan_data.csv` imports fine. `Feb_data.csv` data has all column modified eg. `name.1`, `age.2`and `gender.3`. Likewise for Mar, April,..., Dec data.

Clearly, although a columns names (eg. age) appears in all data, there is no need to "disambiguate" as each column called `age` belongs to different csv file. Therefore, why would the package developer want columns to be modified? Does this add any value? In such case as mine, how would the package author intend to import data of remaining 11 months? Do we import and then manually rename? Also, let's assume I don't want to use `vroom` package either - how do I go about?

Surely, I am missing something here.

Comment: We need a little bit more detail about what you're doing. **If** you are combining the contents of these CSV files into a single data frame/tibble, R will generally automatically add those numeric tags to *disambiguate* the columns.

Comment: You need to do something like `myfilespath |> map(read_csv) |> list_rbind()` to combine the different data frames in one go (this is using `purrr` functions).

Comment: To read in, and combine text files of similar column structure, you might like package {vroom}: https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html#reading-multiple-files

Comment: @BenBolker I have made an edit on my question to provide more information. Yours explanation would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Clearer, but still not clear. Can you give some example code showing *how* you're calling `read_csv`? AFAICT it doesn't have a way to read multiple files at once (from the docs - "file: a path to **a** file", emphasis added). Are you calling it from within a `for` loop (or an `lapply` or `purrr::map` or ... ?) What results do you get if you read "Feb_data.csv" by itself?  Can you post links to some example files?